# How do I block a site locally but accessible using VPN?

Tags: windows, vpn, internet

So this is what I wanna do: I want to block a website, locally, and if I want to visit that site, I must use a VPN. How to do that?

In case you are puzzled by my intention, I want to make certain websites only accessible when I'm using a VPN. If the VPN is turned off, this site is completely blocked, but if I turn it on, everything is fine.

How? Please help? Google hasn't exactly tailored to my peculiar taste.

Edit: Windows platform, windows! Win7 to be more precise.

Comment: What is your Operating System? Without this essential information your question is impossible to answer.

Comment: My apologies, win7. I thought I forgot something but was in a hurry and I couldn't remember what.

Answer (score 0):

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -d <ip> ! -o tun+ -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -d <ip> ! -o tap+ -j DROP
```

Comment: What exactly is this answer?

Comment: Blocking all packets to a specified ip except on all tun/tap devices.

Comment: "tun/tap"? Sounds like Linux to me. "iptables" is not a valid Windows command anyway.

Comment: You're right. I can't see any windows related tag in post.

Comment: Neither can I, but a good answer should indicate the operating system if the question does not require one already.